# Getting the attribute value of a tag when a checkbox is checked with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following HTML, i try to get the sum of all the integers **When the checkbox is checked** 
For instance, here, **when both checkbox are checked** i want to get the sum of 750 and 755

```
<table summary='' id='table_csrdownloadcenter'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>text1</th>
            <th>text2</th>        
            <th>text3</th>
            <th>text4</th>
            <th>text5</th>
            <th>text6</th>
            <th>text7</th>
            <th style="display:none">hidden</th>
            <th>text8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr id='nom_du_pdf'>
            <td class='dc-date'>1</td>
            <td class='dc-dl'>2</td>
            <td class='dc-title'>3</td>
            <td class='dc-area'>4</td>
            <td class='dc-category'>5</td>
            <td class='dc-file'>6</td>
            <td class='dc-ranking'>7</td>
            <td class='hidden_size' style="display:none">750</td>
            <td class='dc-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='chk"+PathFile[i]+"' ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr id='nom_du_pdf2'>
            <td class='dc-date'>1.1</td>
            <td class='dc-dl'>2.2</td>
            <td class='dc-title'>3.3</td>
            <td class='dc-area'>4.4</td>
            <td class='dc-category'>5.5</td>
            <td class='dc-file'>6.6</td>
            <td class='dc-ranking'>7.7</td>
            <td class='hidden_size' style="display:none">755</td>
            <td class='dc-checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='chk"+PathFile[i]+"' ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my try (not working):
I think there is a problem on the second line. How could i travel from the checkbox input to the "hidden_size"tag

```
jQuery(function () {
    var temp = 0;
    $("table#table_csrdownloadcenter tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(){
        temp += $(this).closest('tr').find("hidden_size").Text();

})
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find("hidden_size").Text()` should be `.find(".hidden_size").text()`

Ex:

```
$("table#table_csrdownloadcenter tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
    temp += +$(this).closest('tr').find(".hidden_size").text();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d95hc/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, class should be `.hidden_size`

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find(".hidden_size").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work out the value for you, every time any of the relevant checkboxes is ticked or unticked...

```
$("#table_csrdownloadcenter input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var $checked = $("#table_csrdownloadcenter input:checkbox:checked");
    var total = 0;
    $checked.each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find("td.hidden-size").text(), 10);
        total += value;
    });
    // do what you want with the total here
    alert(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked','#table_csrdownloadcenter').each(function(){
   temp+=$(this).parent().prev('.hidden_size').text();
});
```